# Use SISOTOOL to plot the response of a compensated closed-loop system to a unit ramp?

Tags: matlab, controls, response

I have G=1/(s*(s+3)*(s+4))
and K=0.5

We need a closed loop system so :

```
V=feedback(G*K,1)
sisotool(V)
```

Now I have the plots on the screen, if I go to :

```
Analysis > Response to Step command
```

I get the closed loop response to a step input, but what about ramp ?

**Where in Sisotool can I find a response to a ramp ?**

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no ramp response in sisotool. If you recall, the Laplace transform of a unit ramp input is 1/s^2. Therefore, you need to add an integrator (1/s), and use the step response (which has a Laplace transform of 1/s). I normally add the integrator outside of the loop in the "F" block, and that gives me the unit ramp response.